# Faster numpy.random.shuffle with a length limit?

Tags: numpy, shuffle

I am using `numpy.random.shuffle` to shuffle a list of data. The length of the list is large so I want to randomly sample some of data to do my work.

I implement this using the following code:

```
# data_list is a numpy array of shape (num_data,)
index = np.arange(data_list.size)
np.random.shuffle(index)
index = index[:len_limit]
data = data_list[index]
```

But since index is big, the shuffle is slow.

**Any advice to improve the performance?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common problem. I use the following:

Drawing with replacement

```
idxs = np.random.randint(0, high=len(data), size=(N,))
result = data[idxs]
```

Drawing without replacement

```
import random
idxs = random.sample(xrange(len(data)), N)
result = data[idxs]
```

where `data` is your original dataset and `N` is the number of desired samples. Either should be faster than shuffling, as long as N << len(data).

Comment: Thanks. This method is better than choice when you want to save the index.

Answer (score 1):

Try [`np.random.choice`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html), with `replace=False`.

Example (using the same variables as in the question):

```
data = np.random.choice(data_list, len_limit, replace=False)
```

You'll need numpy version 1.7.0 or later.

Comment: Cool, good to know they finally added this to numpy. It was definitely a missing feature.

Comment: Clean answer. Thank you.

Comment: While it is much more convenient, I'm afraid that under the hood this is doing the exact same as the OP's code, aside of it using `np.random.permutation` instead of `np.random.shuffle`, see [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/ef4806acd0f76cae16c5ce47d0d591173e056e20/numpy/random/mtrand/mtrand.pyx#L1127).

Comment: @Jaime: Now that you mention it, I recall looking at that code.  I forgot that it is the *Python* library (in `random.sample`) that has the heuristic for selecting the method. And there's an open numpy issue about performance: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/2764